# How to match user input to key in dict, and then use the value of that key

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm trying to create my first python program that calculates profits based on the bets placed on different golfers for the coming Masters Tournament. I'm storing golfers and their payout odds in a Dict. I'd like to "place" bets of different amounts on different golfers, and then have the program tell me the profit based on who wins. Just stuck on accessing the members of the dict in my function placeBet()
Heres the code

```py
golfers = {

    "DJ": 11,
    "Speith":9,
    "Bryson":9,
    "JT":11,
    "Jon Rahm":12,
    "Rory":18,
    "Xander":22,
    "Brooks":23,
    "Collin":27,
    "Viktor":33,
    "Paul Casey":35,
    "Tommy Fleetwood":50,
    "Bubba":66,
    "Webb":35,
}

def placeBet():

    print('Which Golfer are you betting on?')
    golfer = input()

    if golfer in golfers.keys():
         print('How much are you betting on ' + golfers[key] + '?' )
         bet = input()
```

When I run the code i get these errors

```py
Which Golfer are you betting on?
DJ

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "masters.py", line 29, in <module>
    placeBet()

  File "masters.py", line 23, in placeBet
    golfer = input()

  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>

NameError: name 'DJ' is not defined
```

Comment: You should learn Python with a recent 3.x version, not a 2.x. If you can't avoid it, you need "raw_input" instead of "input" in 2.x.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming Python 3...

In the `placeBet` function, change `golfers[key]` to `golfer`.  You never defined key, so you cannot use it.  Also, you already know 'golfer', so you don't have to look it up in golfers, just use it.

Also, I assume you want overwrite the bet back to the golfers dict.  If so, add `golfers[golfer] = int(bet)` to the end of the function.  If you want to add the bet, `golfers[golfer] += int(bet)`.  Use float instead of in if bets can include fractional values.

In addition to the changes noted above, I added a few lines to your code to demonstrate the point.  You will of course need to modify the code to suit your desired outcome.

```
golfers = {
"DJ": 11,
"Speith":9,
"Bryson":9,
"JT":11,
"Jon Rahm":12,
"Rory":18,
"Xander":22,
"Brooks":23,
"Collin":27,
"Viktor":33,
"Paul Casey":35,
"Tommy Fleetwood":50,
"Bubba":66,
"Webb":35,
}


def placeBet():
    print('Which Golfer are you betting on?')
    golfer = input()

    if golfer in golfers.keys():
        print('How much are you betting on ' + golfer + '?' )
        bet = input()
        golfers[golfer] += float(bet)
        return golfer, bet, golfers[golfer]
    else:
        return None, None, None


print('Golfer, New Bet, New Bets Total = ', placeBet())
```